# Background image does not appear in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I tried using the js-cumulus library
http://jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/resources/javascript/jscumulus/js-cumulus.html
and in IE7 the blue background image doesn't appear. But it works if I use this jQuery code after initialization of the library.

```
 jQuery('.tagCloud').css('background-image', 'url(bg_blue.gif)');
```

**How can I do this using only CSS since it works in other browsers?**

Comment: Do you have test it with absolute path ?

Comment: I use the same rule for CSS and jQuery and CSS one don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
jQuery('.tagCloud').css('background-image', 'url(/bg_blue.gif)');
```

or

```
jQuery('.tagCloud').css('background-image', 'url("/bg_blue.gif")');
```

or

```
jQuery('.tagCloud').css('background-image', 'url("bg_blue.gif")');
```

Comment: you have to change the URL to:
 **url("/content/resources/javascript/jscumulus/bg_blue.gif")**
so:
**jQuery('.tagCloud').css('background-image', 'url("/content/resources/javascript/jscumulus/bg_blue.gif")');**

Comment: the jQuery code work but not the exact one in css. How can I fix CSS to work in IE7. in IE8 it work.

Comment: @StevenEspinosa If your CSS file is located in a directories or somewhere else then URL path should be matched from that location (of css file).

Comment: I agree with Alex. I think our path is wrong. chrome and FF are smart browsers. You need to make the code correct in order to work in old browsers.

Comment: Yes you don't have errors you have incompatibilities. You need to change if you want this to work? Why you just don't change it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
# Notice the double quotes around the filename.
jQuery('.tagCloud').css('background-image', 'url("bg_blue.gif")');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give css class to that element also.

```
.imageclass
 {
   background-image:url(/bg_blue.gif);
 }


 $('.tagCloud').addClass('imageclass'); // same way you can use remove class
```